# Persistent storage across several runs

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, daemon

I was wondering what would be the best solution for having a storage container that does not loose its contents over several execution times (runs) without using input-output to the filesystem or external database.

Say I have a class foo() which stores integers. From main() I want to call a method that adds an integer and the class does not forget about its former contents.

```
//
// Data storage accross different runs
// This should go into the daemon process
//

#include<iostream>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
  foo(int add): add(add) {}
  void store(int i) {
    vec.push_back( i + add);
  }
private:
  list<int> vec;
  int       add;
};
```

The main function should check for an already running daemon - if not starts it.

```
//
// Main program. Should check whether daemon runs already, if not starts it.
//

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // if (daemon is not running)
  //  start daemon( some_number )

  // call daemon::add( atoi(argv[1]) );
}
```

How would one do this best with shared libraries or with a daemon process? Storage and caller program are on the same Linux host.

Comment: This sounds difficult at best.  Could you tell us more about what you mean by "several runs"?  Will these be related?  Will they run in close sequence?  It may well be easier to use a small file to store the information.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Linux Pipes for interprocess communication.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works for the first call. But how to connect in the next run to the pipe of the previous run?

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes is one way. If you want non blocking though you might want to try the message queue route. Here is a link to one of the system calls http://linux.die.net/man/2/msgctl, you can look at the other calls from there.

Comment: I am not sure if named pipes works here. Is it possible to connect to open pipes of another process? The child doesn't exit executing a service loop awaiting requests. But as mentioned in the question, the 'parent' is executed in several different processes.

What do you mean by message queue route ?

Comment: if your demon is opened first, and is always reading from the pipe, then all clients will be able to write and will exit.

Comment: Another consideration is how would you get the number out when you have "finished" doing what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

May consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached